# No matching version found for @angular/cli@5.2.9

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm New to Angular, while I'm trying to install a particular a particular version of Angular.
I got the below message.

> **C:\Users\Dreams>npm install -g @angular/cli@5.2.9**
>   npm ERR! code ETARGET
>   npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@5.2.9
>   npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
>   npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR! C:\Users\Dreams\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-17T09_42_35_435Z-debug.log

From Browsing I could see the list of Angular versions.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I have also tried by giving 5.2.4 - 5.2.9.

But while I gave a try on 1.4.9 it installed successfully.

My requirement is to install angular 5 on my system.

If we directly install without specifying the version it installs the latest version.

Comment: **Tip:** To find which version(s) of a particular package are available via the npm-registry you can utilize the [npm-view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) command. For example; to list all the version of `@angular/cli`  run the following command: `npm view @angular/cli versions`. You'll notice that version `5.2.9` is _not_ listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no version `@angular/cli@5.2.9`

The version link you are referring to is for `angular` versions. Not `@angular/cli`

Check  [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions) for all available versions

Comment: I have one more doubt is angular/cli version has any connections with angular version .
i.e For eg : If we install angular/cli 6.1.4 will contain the version of angular 6/7 . 
Its just a doubt whether both are interconnected .

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnanK there is no way to do this with a `ng new` command as far as I know. If you install version 6 of the cli, then you have to edit the `package.json`. If you only want angular V5 project, maybe it's easier to just install `@angular/cli@1.7.4`